# Can an Access Combo Box have highlight Colors in the list?

Tags: combobox, background, ms-access-2016

I was wondering if it is possible to highlight certain rows in a combo box different colors?

I have a combo box that is used to generate 3 possible reports depending on what is chosen from the list.
If there is nothing picked it defaults to "**All Records**".  The list contains many department names but out of all of them 2 want specific data reports. I would like to highlight only those 2 departments in the drop list to suggest that they are different reports than the rest. I have this working currently but would like to help the user see the different when picking the report filter.

Like I say, I don't know if this is possible but would like to get it to work if it is...
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it's not possible.

All items on the default combobox control have the same color, and there's no way to change that.

You could try and implement something like this as a custom ActiveX control (essentially re-invent the combobox), but that will complicate matters substantially, so I suggest you let go of the idea.